# Parse Django REST API response with Angular 4

Tags: python, json, django, angular, typescript

I've built a Django REST API using the Django Restapiframework, and it uses a serializer to return a json response:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import WeatherStatistics

class WeatherStatisticsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = WeatherStatistics
        fields = '__all__'
```

In my Angular 4 front-end project I have a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class WeatherstatsService {

  constructor(private http:Http) {
    console.log("Hello World");

    this.getWeatherData();
    // this.getWeatherDataRecords();
  }

  weatherdata: any = {};

  private _WeatherStatsUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/weatherstats/weatherdata';

  getWeatherData() {
    return this.http.get(this._WeatherStatsUrl)
      .map((res:Response) => res.json);
  }

  getWeatherDataRecords() {
    this.getWeatherData().subscribe(weatherdata => {
      console.log(weatherdata)
    })
  }
}
```

And I also have a component that uses that service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WeatherstatsService } from '../weatherstats.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'weather-stats',
  templateUrl: './weather-stats.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./weather-stats.component.css']
})
export class WeatherStatsComponent implements OnInit {

  data: any;

  constructor(private weatherstatsservice: WeatherstatsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.data = this.weatherstatsservice.getWeatherData();
  }

}
```

At the moment all I want it to do is log the json data from my api to the console oninit. So far tho, it does nothing. How do I get the json from Django into Angular?

Comment: are you able to call django viewset, any error in browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you haven't subscribed to your http call, and you can't set asynchronous data in synchronous manner, you need to do it like this:

```
this.weatherstatsservice.getWeatherData().subscribe(data => this.data = data);
```

Second, you have a typo, .json is a function, call it as such

```
.map((res:Response) => res.json());
```

Comment: Getting  a CORS error now? Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/weatherstats/weatherdata: Redirect from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/weatherstats/weatherdata' to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/weatherstats/weatherdata/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: you need to add localhost:4200 to your allowed domains in settings.py

Comment: sorry i was mistaken, the way i handle CORS in django is always to install corsheaders ( django-cors-headers ) and add it to CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST

Comment: Cool - I may end up opening a new question for this coz not sure if I have the restapi framework set up right

Answer (score 1):

That's because you just make the request but no `subscribe` to it's value when it's come back from backend. If you want to get data from your component I sugget to use

In your component.

```
 this.weatherstatsservice.getWeatherData().subscribe(data => this.data = data);
```

or call `this.weatherstatservice.getWeatherDataRecords()` from `service` (but you won't be sure when it's comeback from `server` so you should make an observer to this or just use first method) and then grab data from `service`.